# iPhone app compatibility

Tags: xcode

i just want how to make sure that my application will be compatible with iPhone 4, 3GS,3G,iPad touch ?
should i set up any parameters in Xcode or interface builder or both ?
THX in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

To force you application to be used only with some devices, this is done while publishing your application on the AppStore.

Speaking about code, the compatibility factor is not the device, but the iOS version. In that case, in your build settings, you can set the "iOS Deployment Target".